# STM32F411 Nucleo board - what the ferrite bead is used for?

Tags: pcb, stm32, schematics, stm32f4

I'm trying to design my own pcb for the stm32f411 and when i saw the datasheet of the stm32f411 ( http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00115249.pdf ) and then the schematics for the stm32f411 nucleo board i was a little confused.

In pin 13 (Vref+), in the schematics there is an ferrite bead.I can't understand why it used in the Vref+ pin (since there isn't any mention to it in the datasheet not even the explanation of the Vref+ pin function.

[image: Image from schematics of ST - Vref pin and inductor]
Image is from ST schematics

So, my question is, for what the inductor is used in this application and is it really necessary?

Grateful

**Edited**

Comment: Note that its not an inductor as in a coil or similar, but a ferrite bead.

Comment: Could you explain why a ferrite bead is being used in this application? Grateful

Comment: Beads stop current inrush when power is connected and suppress HF noise. My guess is that it is to remove power supply noise from the analogue voltage reference.

Comment: Ok, grateful for your answer. So, do you think it is mandatory to have the bead there? Removing it would cause any problem to the device (this is the first time i see ferrite beads and never worked it them).

Answer (score 3):

That bead seems unconnected by default, through solder  bridge 57, which I suspect is normally open.  If 57 is closed, it connects Vdd  to AVdd, but prevents noise from Vdd hitting the analog ref by increasing high freq impedence.

Comment: That is what i don't undertstand. SB57 is closed, so there is an 0 resistor there. Supposely AVdd is the same as Vdd (Vdd=Avdd), so why there is an bead there? Grateful

Comment: If SB57 is closed, then AVdd is connected to Vdd through the bead.  Think of the bead as a short circuit at DC, with the impedance going up as frequency goes up.  AVdd is thus a low-pass filtered version of Vdd, which is good in case there is noise on Vdd.

Comment: Ah, ok, grateful

Answer (score 0):

Noise on the analog reference means noise on the adc converted signal.
So, for a good adc conversion (ENOB = effective number of bits),
the noise on the analog reference is crucial.
I am pretty sure the bead is to reduce noise.
It is a common method.